# C++ - retrieving current date and time fast

Tags: c++, performance, datetime

I've been experimenting with different ways of retrieving the current date and time, but frankly, none of them satisfy my performance needs.

Here is the most performant function I've found of all

```
std::string format_time(const char* format)
{
    char date[256];
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    std::strftime(date, sizeof(date), format, std::gmtime(&in_time_t));
    return date;
}
```

I have benchmarked with a simple timer class, and according to it, the function takes ~**15μs**
I know that it's humanly impossible to notice any overhead from this, however, my curiosity still stands.

Is there a way to retrieve the current date and time faster than this?
I am more than willing to trade code elegancy for performance, even if the code goes near the metal

Comment: You've tried going full-on C and calling `time` to get a `time_t` instead of using chrono and then converting the time point into a `time_t`?

Comment: Start throwing away conveniences you don't need.  For example do you need the local time, or will UTC do?  Do you need a general format not known until run time?  Are you willing to custom write formatting to a fixed format spec?  General libraries can't make any of these assumptions.

Comment: Excuse me for not mentioning this. It seems time_t creates a lot more overhead.

I need the local time. Yes, I am willing to custom write the formatting.
I'm not sure what you mean under general format not known until runtime
Usually, the format is always known at compile-time. 
Honestly, I can do just fine with separate functions for hours, minutes, seconds, etc. I don't need the actual formatting that's being done, because I'm already doing it myself, in a way.

Comment: `time_t` is a type, not a function.  What platform are you on?  Are you measuring with optimizations on?

Comment: I am on Win10, and yes, O2 optimizations on MSVC. 
Offtopic, for a busy guy like you, you've always been very helpful around here, thank you.

Comment: And yes, I know that time_t is a type. I meant that simply creating a time_t object creates the overhead.

Comment: `to_time_t` can be replaced with `duration_cast<seconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count()`, which is as fast as it can get.   However I don't think that will change anything: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/chrono#L589-L591

Comment: If your local time zone doesn't have daylight saving, you can save quite a bit of time by adding your UTC offset to get local time manually.  If you do have daylight saving but it follows regular rules, you can still save lot of time by coding those rules manually, as opposed to having `strftime` look them up.  For example search for "utc_offset_Eastern_US" here:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html  You can use that same datelib to convert the `time_point` into a `{y, m, d, h, M, s}` struct and then do your own formatting.

Comment: The “bottleneck” here is almost certainly not in **retrieving** the date and time, but in **formatting** the result.

Comment: Yes, most definitely. That's why I said that simply having separate functions for the current hour, minute, second, date, would work just fine. I don't need the formatting at all.

Comment: Unless you need super-fine/milliseconds resolution and accuracy, it seems like memoization might be a useful optimization here.  i.e. if you know the result can't change more than once per second, cache the result and reuse it for up to one second rather than recomputing it on every call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this [open-source preview of the C++20 chrono library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) (which works with C++11/14/17) to achieve about 100ns per call on macOS.

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void
to_chars(char*, char* l, unsigned long long x)
{
    do
    {
        *--l = static_cast<char>((x % 10) + '0');
        x /= 10;
    } while(x != 0);
}

// yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff
// 01234567890123456789012345
auto
format_current_time()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    auto tp = system_clock::now();
    static auto const tz = current_zone();
    static auto info = tz->get_info(tp);
    if (tp >= info.end)
        info = tz->get_info(tp);
    auto tpl = local_days{} + (tp + info.offset - sys_days{});
    auto tpd = floor<days>(tpl);
    year_month_day ymd{tpd};
    hh_mm_ss hms{tpl-tpd};
    array<char, 21+hms.fractional_width> result{};
    auto r = result.data();
    fill(r, r + result.size()-1, '0');
    r[4] = r[7] = '-';
    r[10] = ' ';
    r[13] = r[16] = ':';
    r[19] = '.';
    ::to_chars(r, r+4, int{ymd.year()});
    ::to_chars(r+5, r+7, unsigned{ymd.month()});
    ::to_chars(r+8, r+10, unsigned{ymd.day()});
    ::to_chars(r+11, r+13, hms.hours().count());
    ::to_chars(r+14, r+16, hms.minutes().count());
    ::to_chars(r+17, r+19, hms.seconds().count());
    ::to_chars(r+20, r+20+hms.fractional_width, hms.subseconds().count());
    return result;
}

int
main()
{
    auto t0 = format_current_time();
    auto t1 = format_current_time();
    auto t2 = format_current_time();
    auto t3 = format_current_time();
    auto t4 = format_current_time();
    auto t5 = format_current_time();
    auto t6 = format_current_time();
    auto t7 = format_current_time();
    auto t8 = format_current_time();
    auto t9 = format_current_time();
    auto t10 = format_current_time();
    auto t11 = format_current_time();
    auto t12 = format_current_time();
    auto t13 = format_current_time();
    auto t14 = format_current_time();
    auto t15 = format_current_time();
    auto t16 = format_current_time();
    auto t17 = format_current_time();
    auto t18 = format_current_time();
    auto t19 = format_current_time();
    std::cout << t0.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t1.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t2.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t3.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t4.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t5.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t6.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t7.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t8.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t9.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t10.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t11.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t12.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t13.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t14.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t15.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t16.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t17.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t18.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << t19.data() << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

```
2021-01-09 17:44:55.778356
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034498
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034498
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034498
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034498
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034499
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034500
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034500
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034500
2021-01-09 17:44:56.034500
```

This code assumes that the device does not change the current time zone during the application run (which may not be true for a mobile device).  If that assumption can't be made, then the time per call balloons to about 50us.  However a compromise could be made to check `current_zone()` say only once per second (or whatever) to bring the average time back down.

As written, the first step is to get the current UTC time:

```
auto tp = system_clock::now();
```

The next step is to get the current local time zone setting, and all the information there is to know about this time zone setting at this time.  All of this information is stored in function-local statics as it is assumed that the time zone doesn't change at all, and that the UTC offset changes rarely (e.g. twice a year):

```
static auto const tz = current_zone();
static auto info = tz->get_info(tp);
```

`info` contains an `end` member that is a UTC timestamp that marks the end of when this information is valid.  If `tp` exceeds the range of validity, then the information is updated (this typically happens at most twice a year):

```
if (tp >= info.end)
    info = tz->get_info(tp);
```

Next the UTC offset is applied to the current `system_clock` `time_point` and stored in distinct `chrono::time_point` type called `local_time` (with the same precision as `system_clock::time_point`):

```
auto tpl = local_days{} + (tp + info.offset - sys_days{});
```

Then this `chrono::time_point` is broken down into two data structures.  The first is a `{year, month, day}` data structure:

```
auto tpd = floor<days>(tpl);
year_month_day ymd{tpd};
```

The first line simply truncates the `time_point` to `days` precision (a count of days since the local epoch).  Then the second line converts the count of days into a `{year, month, day}` data structure in the civil calendar.

Then the local time of day is converted into a `{hours, minutes, seconds, subseconds}` data structure:

```
hh_mm_ss hms{tpl-tpd};
```

The units of "subseconds" depends on `system_clock::duration`.  On macOS it is 1us.  On Windows it is 100ns.

Everything after this is formatting the values in `ymd` and `hms`.  The results are stored in a `std::array<char, N>` to avoid an allocation.  I know you have your own formatting, but I show mine so that you know how to access the values in `ymd` and `hms`.  On Windows, `hms.fractional_width` is the compile-time integral constant 7 (6 on macOS, 9 when using gcc).

Answer (score 1):

**MSVC only**:

`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now` uses the underlying `QueryPerformanceCounter`, which is designed for this purpose.

I get `14 ns` per call for `now`, which is remarkably close to time I get of `12 ns` for an API call to to `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

You aren't really going to get better performance than this, since it queries the CPU directly from hal.dll. `now` is marginally slower only due to also calling `QueryPerformanceFrequency` to convert the result to seconds.

I imagine your overhead is from formatting and fetching the locale, not from the query call itself. Leave the formatting until needed.